# Automatically read a file - easy

Tags: graph, plot, readfile

This should be a really easy question, but I just cant seem to get it done, I have a section of code calculating X Y points on a graph, then saving them to file.

If a certain condition is met I want to plot the values on a graph, I am using this code to plot the graph- http://www.kodejava.org/examples/805.html

But I don't want it to ask for the user to point to the file location, I just want it to open a file which has a directory hard coded in, and plot it automatically. So basically remove the buttons at the top and carry out the commands of the buttons automatically.

Would be fantastic if somebody could point me in the right direction, I'm a physicist not a coding expert so as much help as possible would be excellent.

Hope I can help one of you in return sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Inside `public static void main`, just above `frame.setVisible(true);` insert `openButton.setVisible(false);`

2) Inside `class GraphPanel`, inside the method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` insert `datapanel.actionPerformed(e);` as the first line.

3) Inside `class DataPanel` inside `public void actionPerformed` comment out from the beginning `JFrame fileFrame = new JFrame();` to `initialized = readFile(datafile);`

4) Just after the comment, insert `initialized = readFile(new File("path_to_data_file"));`

Now if you open, and press plot, the hard coded file will be read and plot will be drawn.

Heck,, I don't care if this gets downvoted :). I've never touched Java. After reading your problem, specially `I'm a physicist not a coding expert` first i searched in google how to compile and run a java file. Then started reading the java program. I even made another version which does not need the button press also, Just open and your graph will be drawn. But that's only if needed, then provided. "Welcome to my java attempt" :)

Update:

For doing without pressing plot, in GraphPanel and DataPanel, and rename the `actionPerformed` methods to something else like `GraphPanel::start_working` and `DataPanel::start_working` Now inside `GraphPanel::start_working` call  `DataPanel::start_working` instead of earlier `datapanel.actionPerformed(e);` . If compiler cribs, add some empty `actionPerformed` for compilation. (perhaps we can remove the `implements` ) Now your flow is ready without any user action. you just need to start it. So you set `plotButton.setVisible(false);` to hide the plot button and call `graphpanel.start_work();` to start the flow in main.

Update:

Inside GraphPanel

```
public void start_working() {
        datapanel.start_working()
        if (!datapanel.isInitialized()) {
            return;
        }
        datapanel.refreshData();
        panel.setDisplayPlot(true);
        panel.update(panel.getGraphics());
        frame.setSize(700, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
```

And inside DataPanel

```
 public void start_working(ActionEvent e) {
        initialized = readFile(new File("PATH_TO_FILE");
        panel.update(panel.getGraphics());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

in main last 5 lines

```
openButton.setVisible(false);
plotButton.setVisible(false);
graphpanel.start_working();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Also I don't see how it is a graph problem, please edit the tags

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You have saved my next few days from programming hell!

Comment: which bit did you change to get it to draw the graph without pressing plot?

Comment: Updated the answer. If you follow this, there will be redundant code which can be removed. But perhaps that won't cause any problem as long it is working

Comment: Awesome, just one point - the 'GraphPanel::start_working' part what code would I use? thanks again Abasu

Comment: Thanks Abasu, this is excellent help. I follow your update code but when compiling I get 'GraphPanel is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed)java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener'    - don't suppose you know what is happening here, I've been looking at a few things but nothing has improved it yet. thanks in advance

Dont

Comment: check in update `If compiler cribs, add some empty actionPerformed for compilation.`

Comment: I removed every reference to actionPerformed and not it doesn't error, can compile but the graph is not plotted.

Thanks for all your help, Ill just stick to having to press Open and Plot each time. You have been a massive help, thank you.